# Postgresql truncate table with foreing keys? without cascading?

Tags: postgresql, truncate, cascade

is it possible to truncate a table which has a foreing key reference without truncating the child table?

It should be possible by disabling and enabling the foreing key check?

But in my case the name of the foreing key constraint can be dynamic or defined somewhere else hence i don't know it runtime?

is it possible to get this name,  disable it, truncate a table and then enable it in one query?

If so how?

Comment: If you disable the constraint on the dependent table and then truncate the referenced table, you will not be able to reenable the constraint on the dependent table.  If you insist on pursuing this, then look at `information_schema`.

Comment: But if you truncate the table you can't enable the foreign key anymore as the references from the child table to that (truncated) table aren't valid anymore

Comment: I basically want clear all rows for that table, and currebtly i cannot do so due to foreing key reference... The table itself is the child table.. I will in a different step reinsert the rows, but to do so i need to delete them..

Comment: What is the point of of deleting then later reinserting, the same data? It does not change the state of the database.

Comment: I know its not efficient, but this is done since  when an update occur all the prior entries will also occour reappear and to avoid double insertion i reinsert everything @Belayer

Comment: Likely too late for the OP, but `INSERT  ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;` avoids double insertion, too.